# annotation mapping bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne not fetching?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm clearly struggling to understand this so help greatly appreciated...

I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class ParentEntity
{
...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long id;
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ChildEntity> children;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class ChildEntity
{
...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Long id;
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private ParentEntity parent;
...
}
```

in my db i have:

```
parent
------
parent_id: 1

child
------
child_id: 1, parent_id: 1
```

However

```
((Parent) session.get(Parent.class, 1)).getChildren()
```

returns null.

can anyone see what I have missing?

thanks, p.

**EDIT**

It seems to be more-so to do with session state in that the collection is not populated in the context of the same session, but the collection is populated in the next session...

consider the following:

```
void setupRender()
{
    debug("existing not just added", (ParentEntity) session.get(ParentEntity.class, 13L));

    ParentEntity parent = new ParentEntity();
    session.save(parent);

    ChildEntity child = new ChildEntity();
    child.setParent(parent);
    session.save(child);

    debug("new one before commit", parent);

    sessionManager.commit();

    debug("new one after commit", parent);

    debug("new one after re-fetch", (ParentEntity) session.load(ParentEntity.class, parent.getId()));
}

private void debug(String prefix, ParentEntity parent)
{
    log.debug(prefix + ": parent id: " + parent.getId() + ", Children is "
            + (parent.getChildren() == null ? "null" : "size:" + parent.getChildren().size()));
}
```

results in the following output:

```
DEBUG - existing not just added: parent id: 13, Children is size:1
DEBUG - new one before commit: parent id: 23, Children is null
DEBUG - new one after commit: parent id: 23, Children is null
DEBUG - new one after re-fetch: parent id: 23, Children is null
```

so if it's due to session state, and commit isn't enough to trigger a re-fetch, what do I have to do to get the mapping to fetch the collection?

thanks again!

Comment: Do you get any useful information when looking at the Hibernate debug data?

Comment: please see edit. BTW db is postgres, i'm also in a tapestry environment using tapestry-hibernate module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, commit doesn't trigger refresh of the session cache.

The typical approach here is to use session-per-request pattern, so that you close the session immediately after commit, and open another session for the following transactions (though it's not an option if you use [Open Session in View pattern](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView)).

Another good practice that may help to solve this problem is to modify both sides of bidirectional relationship simultaneously:

```
public class ParentEntity {
    ...
    public void addChild(ChildEntity c) {
        children.add(c);
        c.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

This way you can keep objects in the session cache in consistent state.

Finally, if you actually need to refresh an object inside a session you can call `Session.refresh()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding cascade attribute as part of your OneToMany in parent entity might solve the problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class ParentEntity
{
...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long id;
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChildEntity> children;
...
}
```

Then to persist the row

```
ParentEntity parent = new ParentEntity();

ChildEntity child = new ChildEntity();
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
session.save(parent);
```

This will also delete all the children when deleting a parent.

Comment: Correct, but not the issue here :)

Answer (score 0):

In your original question it implied that the data already existed in the database before you open the session, this was a critical piece of information to know you save it in the same session...

Here is the official Hibernate guidance on that topic by the way:
(taken from http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-CommonProblems)

**I'm having trouble with a bidirectional association.**

When you update a bidirectional association you must update both ends.

```
parent.getChildren().add(child);
child.setParent(parent);
```

It's best to do this in an association management method of your persistent class.

**I'm still having trouble!**

Read the documentation! There's a detailed section about "Parent/Child Relationships" in chapter 16 of the reference documentation including code examples.

Comment: The fact that it's a list is irrelevant. Also, if `getChildren()` is returning null, then a `Parent` is successfully being loaded, thus reading from the database seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

[The solution I use at the moment](http://amanica.blogspot.com/2011/08/jpa-not-instantiating-mapped.html) is to initialize the collection manually during construction:

```
private List<ChildEntity> children 
    = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>;
```

I'm not sure if that is a good practice, but it works and is simple.